# Notifying users that have been assigned to a campaign

Tags: user, campaign, notification

Hey I've been working away on this problem for a while now and I really hope somebody can help me out.

Basically I'm building a resource allocation tool that enables campaign creators to assign certain sales people to work on certain campaigns. So far I've added a custom object called "Assigned_Resource__c" which is a one to many look-up on Campaign and User. This basically means that I can create a list of users on a campaign. I'm wondering is there a way I could send an email notification to these users letting them know that they have been assigned?

The tricky part is that my manager has said that I am only allowed to add new code if it cant be done within the system.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your need, you will not need to write code. Here is the approach:

1. Use workflow on `Assigned_Resource__c` instead and set evaluation criteria "Every time edited, subsequently meet criteria'
2. Set the condition in formula editor as `ISCHANGED(Campaign Lookup field)`. This condition will return true whenever the field changes and fire workflow action.
3. Set up workflow action "send email".

Comment: I don't think a lookup to User was created on Campaign, rather a new junction object Assigned_Resource__c between User and Campaign.

Comment: Yes, I read it. However the approach would be similar to this.

Comment: That's great thanks Ashwani, I'll give that a try now